How can I validate if my miner works?
I recently challenged myself to build a BTC Miner that operates on solo.ckpool.org,
yeah i know chances are close to zero to find a nonce (especially that not only nonce is in the process) but i focused solely on iterating through nonce search space for simplicity.
Now i would like to test if mining a block really works.
But there is a caveat, how do i find a block with a known nonce i could test against my miner?
In perfect world that would be in the same format as the pool provides (JSON)
so that i could test the whole process :
{"result":[[["mining.notify","716b514d"]],"b3b4c76e",8],"id":1,"error":null}
...
{"params":["64851638000e64a0","ea9b003e15e90810e28b429926aab824428f263d00007e570000000000000000","01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff3503dfcf0c000435db1f6604880b42150c","0a636b706f6f6c112f736f6c6f2e636b706f6f6c2e6f72672fffffffff03749ff72a000000001976a914c987a18977a2139835193b3df2eea097f834966888ac6a7be0000000000016001451ed61d2f6aa260cc72cdf743e4e436a82c010270000000000000000266a24aa21a9ed9e5037be4e44df5dc4e8ba01b1ce40d5b234a6cf219951d9ad0e7ff6d839369300000000",["f0a795e17eb9c4ab7e6106c46fd35d254a032749fcbe536b3035376fdd3869ab","84265449c5b8f1ec096432562e0386f2ca159ba22a092bbad363c5599c3512a6","d91e4922831da4ef4f4151bbc66c7f4087ae34578f579ae771a343d0ffbeafd3","fc1fb85d56bcde6c01f856f083407d54af4569c1cdc4c3d790a85457a6170b22","30ed434482df77cd1292ad4f15b3233846e9e455f1bb463bb8e128b28e22449f","0205f58e1715b8e9f87df5c7f3a2006394f92be064110c20e78df8562560e3d8","e3ff80576d069cd29392bc1e9220d16f5ab6d9783c3f71cdc112ec661f7150ec","c6857a7c5f1c5d979f94b8d6c0d0d099e92a9dc9dd093fa94840807584855e5c","7d98a0da3a3566ce9add97aaa193dc6e94a6f29367bb4af38e175b991deae66f","99dadd674098d37eba4f3464e3b32d7894269598f8ec9f874b9e06cdef357f19","b1e11113d0575f1253cef2e84d291cc1668bbd268930faf45760bea295c37dd7","3bafb324838086a13c0b2baa3ffa9f582fd279e1d490d26ad98ab45cd422638c"],"20000000","17034219","661fdb35",true],"id":null,"method":"mining.notify"}

Is there a way to find such payload with a known nonce on which i could test run and verify if my miner is really working fine?
To clarify, i am looking for a block where a nonce was found and it is in the format of a json - the same that the pool is sending to miners.

On solo.ckpool.org page, under "Statistics" you can enter your bitcoin address (the one used to run the miner in) to see your miner statistics
If you like to backtest a sucessfully mined block, you'll have to check if the mining software support such manual command.
If it doesn't, you can create an http request manually (eg with PostMan) that include the backtest and send it to the pool. Anyway it won't be much relevant as it does not proove the miner will effectivly behave like this once a real nonce is found.

The issue I'm encountering involves verifying my mining setup against a block that has a known nonce. Typically, when you receive a block from the mining pool, you have no option but to attempt to discover its nonce through guesswork among other parameters. To address this, I've considered an alternative method: feeding my miner a block where the nonce is already known. This would allow me to check if my miner can reproduce the exact same hash and correctly compare it against the target.

Your worker name is your Bitcoin recieving address. There is a place where it says to paste your worker name on solo ck pool webpage. To access user statistics, enter your BTC address below and press enter:
Copy and past your bitcoin reciving address. If you are on pool it should show information like your hashrate. It will look like this:
hashrate1m": "1.78P",
"hashrate5m": "1.46P",
"hashrate1hr": "820T",
"hashrate1d": "52.5T",
"hashrate7d": "7.63T",
"lastshare": 1735488221,
"workers": 1,
"shares": 1079000000,
"bestshare": 622613854.7318306,
"bestever": 622613854,
"authorised": 1735484342,
"worker": [
